# Detect volatile functions as input for my custom function

Tags: office-js, exceljs

I have a custom function which takes a date as an input. As a result, TODAY() is a total valid input. However I don't like the fact that TODAY() is a volatile function which can slow down my users' spreadsheets.

Is there anyway to detect volatile functions as input for my custom function so that I can return a message to my users? Thanks a lot